# Transposing Strings

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, transpose

I am exploring mlb baseball statcast data, which is at the pitch level. I want to summarize the pitches at the plate appearance level. The relevant columns:

```
game_pk | pitcher_id | batter_id | inning | pitch_number | pitch_type | plt_apprnc_pk (unique)
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
492321  |   542881   |   518466  |    2   |       1      |    FF      |   4923215428815184662
492321  |   543475   |   571448  |    1   |       2      |    SL      |   4923215434755714481
492321  |   543475   |   571448  |    1   |       1      |    FF      |   4923215434755714481
492321  |   543475   |   571448  |    1   |       3      |    FF      |   4923215434755714481
```

I am working on a query only showing one iteration of each plate appearance (plt_apprnc_pk), followed by pitch_number columns (1st pitch, 2nd pitch, 3rd pitch, etc...) showing each pitch type for the respective pitch number. In essence I want to transpose the pitch_type by pitch_number.

```
plt_apprnc_pk (unique)| first_pitch | second_pitch | third_pitch
----------------------------------------------------------------
  4923215434755714481 |     SL      |      FF      |     FF
```

I tried doing this with Case statements (ie CASE WHEN pitch_number = 1 THEN pitch_type END). I keep getting multiple rows for each plt_apprnc_pk.

```
plt_apprnc_pk (unique)| first_pitch | second_pitch | third_pitch
------------------------------------------------------------------
  4923215434755714481 |     SL      |      NULL    |    NULL
  4923215434755714481 |    NULL     |      FF      |    NULL
  4923215434755714481 |    NULL     |      NULL    |     FF
```

What is the best way to transpose these strings based on pitch_number while keeping only one iteration of the unique key??

Comment: First, answer the following question: What is the theoretical maximum number of pitches per appearance?  That's the number of columns you'll need and you'll need that number of columns for every row in this result.

Comment: According to baseball rules, there's no theoretical limit. The batter can foul off an unlimited number of times. In practice no batter has fouled off an infinite number of times -- yet.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> *I tried doing this with Case statements (ie CASE WHEN pitch_number = 1 THEN pitch_type END). I keep getting multiple rows for each plt_apprnc_pk.*

The pattern here is called conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT plt_apprnc_pk
     ,MAX(CASE WHEN pitch_number = 1 THEN pitch_type END) AS first_pitch 
     ,MAX(CASE WHEN pitch_number = 2 THEN pitch_type END) AS second_pitch 
     ,MAX(CASE WHEN pitch_number = 3 THEN pitch_type END) AS thrid_pitch 
     -- ...
     --,MAX(CASE WHEN pitch_number = n THEN pitch_type END) AS nth_pitch 
FROM tab
GROUP BY plt_apprnc_pk;
```

Note: The maximum "pitch_number" has to be known in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You may use Like this in your query I think useful this:

```
ISNULL(max(case when pitch_number = 1 THEN pitch_type end),0) as Default_name
```